# How to interpret this interaction in R?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, interpretation

How would you interpret this interaction?
The structure of the data is all integer variables. 
Inc.fix= income, age.fix=age, profit99= profit

```
 Call:
  lm(formula = Profit99 ~ Age.fix + Inc.fix + Age.fix:Inc.fix, 
       data = pilg)

      Residuals:
           Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
          -421.86 -148.76  -84.45   55.67 1938.70 

              Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
                 (Intercept)     -139.9706    11.1273 -12.579  < 2e-16 ***
                 Age.fix           37.8453     2.4430  15.491  < 2e-16 ***
                 Inc.fix           26.5252     1.9790  13.403  < 2e-16 ***
                 Age.fix:Inc.fix   -2.2217     0.4475  -4.965 6.92e-07 ***
                  ---
                 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                Residual standard error: 268.1 on 31630 degrees of freedom
                Multiple R-squared:  0.03443,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.03434 
                 F-statistic: 375.9 on 3 and 31630 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: This is more of a statistics question than an R programming question so have flagged for transfer to Cross-Validated.

Comment: It might be easier to pick a handful of ages, a couple incomes, plug those numbers into the equation with the betas, and see how profit changes as you vary one parameter, the other, or both. then see if you can generalize like the answers below do

Comment: Another possibility would be to try visualizing the results. `car::scatter3d()` might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

- The expected profit when `Age` and `Inc` (income?) are both 0 equals -139
- when `Inc` is zero, for every additional unit of `Age`, the expected profit increases by 38
- when `Age` is zero, for every additional unit of `Inc`, the expected profit increases by 27
- for every additional unit of `Inc`, the slope with respect to `Age` (expected increase in profit per unit of `Age`) decreases by 2.2 (i.e. changes by -2.2), and *vice versa* (for additional unit of `Age`, the slope with respect to `Inc` also decreases by 2.2).

Answer (score 4):

Interpreting regression models/linear models can be tricky. In my head, I always "read" the formula: *Profit is a function of (or can be predicted by) of age and income, but not necessarily additive (hence the interaction term)*.

All of your *P*-values are signification, therefore you need to consider all of the term in the regression. Looking at the individual coefficients:

- As age increase profits increase (because the coefficient is positive)
- As income increases, profits increase (because the coefficient is positive as well)
- As both age and income increase, profit decreases increase as much (because the coefficient is negative)

The last coefficient is hardest to interpret. The strength of the interaction depends upon the coefficient values. In your case,

Also, you might want to checkout the [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics)) article on the topic for more background.

Comment: The only part of this I would disagree with is "All of your P-values are [significant], therefore you need to consider all of the term[s] ...".  IMO you need to consider all of the terms that you put into the model, whether they're significant or not.

Comment: @BenBolker That's a good nuanced catch. Personally, in my own data analysis, I would either use confidence or credible intervals and avoid _P_-values, but that's a different topic for a different post...

Comment: @whuber, Thank you! I was answering the question on Stack Overflow when it got migrated over. Also, I browsed your CV. Your research looks interesting.

Comment: I hope you will consider answering more questions over here :-).